# copying the whole directory with some exceptions using scp

Tags: scp

I have to retrieve a directory with all the subdirectories from a server. However, I want to exclude some file with a specific extension (they are heavy and useless to me).

```
scp -r myname@servername:fodertocpy .
```

does copy the whole directory but I don't know how to exclude files with `.abc` extension, let's say.

I would like to use `scp` because it already automatically handles my passwords.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with only `scp` as `scp` doesn't have an exclude flag. I assume you want to utilise your key auth you've already setup with ssh /scp.  If so I would do `rsync over ssh` - it would then utilise your existing key authentication.

Something like this would work:

```
rsync --exclude '*.abc' -avz -e ssh myname@servername:foldertocpy .
```

Have a look at the `man rsync` for an explanation of the flags.

Hope this helps,

Will